# Zip non sequential list based on condition

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scalaz

I have a scenario where I to zip two lists in scala based on condition. 
They might not be in sequence. What is the best way to do that?

I want to group DirectRetailCM and DirectRetailCM with same requestId as a tuple.

```
object Main extends App {
   case class SalesDoc(val id: Int, val name: String, val requestId: String) {}
   val list = List(
     SalesDoc(1, "ILLEGAL", "1"),
     SalesDoc(2, "DirectRetailCM", "1"),

     SalesDoc(3, "DirectRetailOffsetInvoice", "2"),
     SalesDoc(4, "DirectRetailCM", "2"),
     SalesDoc(5, "OTHER", "2"),

     SalesDoc(5, "DirectRetailCM", "LEFTOUT"),
     SalesDoc(6, "ILLEGAL2", "4"),

     SalesDoc(5, "OTHER", "3"),
     SalesDoc(7, "DirectRetailOffsetInvoice", "4"),
     SalesDoc(8, "DirectRetailCM", "4")
  )

 // I expect zip results of drOffsetInvoice and drCms as
List(
  (SalesDoc(3, "DirectRetailOffsetInvoice", "2"), SalesDoc(4, "DirectRetailCM", "2")),
  (SalesDoc(7, "DirectRetailOffsetInvoice", "4"), SalesDoc(8, "DirectRetailCM", "4"))
  )
}
```

The initial approach that I can think of was

- group directRetailCM -  list.filter(e => e.name == "DirectRetailCM")
- group DirectRetailOffsetInvoice - list.filter(e => e.name == "DirectRetailOffsetInvoice")
- **Zip both  - But might not be in sequence**
- **there could be rows which don't have counterparts**

Can you please suggest any other approach that I need to consider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// You don't need the val keyword for a case class
case class SalesDoc(id: Int, name: String, requestId: String)

val list = List(
  SalesDoc(1, "ILLEGAL", "1"),
  SalesDoc(2, "DirectRetailCM", "1"),

  SalesDoc(3, "DirectRetailOffsetInvoice", "2"),
  SalesDoc(4, "DirectRetailCM", "2"),
  SalesDoc(5, "OTHER", "2"),

  SalesDoc(5, "DirectRetailCM", "LEFTOUT"),
  SalesDoc(6, "ILLEGAL2", "4"),

  SalesDoc(5, "OTHER", "3"),
  SalesDoc(7, "DirectRetailOffsetInvoice", "4"),
  SalesDoc(8, "DirectRetailCM", "4")
)

// Find all of the DirectRetailOffsetInvoice items
val offsets = list.filter(_.name == "DirectRetailOffsetInvoice")

// Map over all of the DirectRetailOffsetInvoice items and see if there is matching DirectRetailCM item
val maybeMatched = offsets.map(offset => {
  val maybeCm = list.find(i => i.requestId == offset.requestId && i.name == "DirectRetailCM")

  // Return a tuple of type (SalesDoc, Option[SalesDoc])
  (offset, maybeCm)
})

// Map over the tuples and only take the ones where there was a match, and extract it from the Option to create a tuple of (SalesDoc, SalesDoc)
val output = maybeMatched.collect { case (s1, Some(s2)) => (s1, s2) }

output.foreach(println)
// (SalesDoc(3,DirectRetailOffsetInvoice,2),SalesDoc(4,DirectRetailCM,2))
// (SalesDoc(7,DirectRetailOffsetInvoice,4),SalesDoc(8,DirectRetailCM,4))
```

Comment: Thanks Tyler, I will probably use one more filter on DirectRetailCM to avoid looping through for each DirectRetailOffsetInvoice.

Comment: If you have a lot more rows than your example suggests, you would probably want to build a map instead so you could have much faster lookups.

Answer (score 1):

```
list.filter(s => s.name == "DirectRetailCM" || s.name == "DirectRetailOffsetInvoice")
    .groupBy(_.requestId)
    .collect { case (_, List(a, b)) => (a, b) }
    .toList

// List[(SalesDoc, SalesDoc)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with standard Scala combinators

```
list
  .filter(sd => sd.name == "DirectRetailCM" || sd.name == "DirectRetailOffsetInvoice")
  .groupBy(_.requestId)
  .flatMap {
     case (_, List(a,b)) => List(a->b)
     case _ => List.empty
  }
```

Which gives you :

```
 res3: scala.collection.immutable.Map[SalesDoc,SalesDoc] = 
       Map(
         SalesDoc(3,DirectRetailOffsetInvoice,2) -> SalesDoc(4,DirectRetailCM,2), 
         SalesDoc(7,DirectRetailOffsetInvoice,4) -> SalesDoc(8,DirectRetailCM,4))
```

If the input sequence is not sorted with `DirectRetailOffsetInvoice` being before `DirectRetailCM`, you will need to handle it.